# Simplifying matrices in R to give faster results trying to calculate a BI-SIM value

Tags: r, recursion, combinations

I am trying to do a specific method of matching similar words.  Please don't suggest other matching algorithms unless they are using this method.  This is to calculate a BI-SIM value (there is a few extra steps to calculate BI-SIM but I will spare the details)

Lets assume we have two words - **book** and **boat**.

They are compared by using letter pairings: "bo", "oo", "ok" compared to "bo", "oa", "at"

If the letter pair is identical it gets 1 point. If the only one letter (in the correct position) it gets 0.5 points.

Letter pairs can be omitted, but otherwise letter pairs can't be used out of sequence.

Highest overall score is wanted if there is more than one way to score

| a | b | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **bo** | **bo** | 1 |
| **o**o | **o**a | 0.5 |
| ok | at | 0 |

**Total score 1.5**

This example is fairly simple.  It gets more complicated when we add a longer word like **booking** and **blinking**

| a | b | b score | c | c score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **b**o | **b**l | 0.5 | **b**l | 0.5 |
| oo | li | 0 | li, in | 0 |
| o**k** | in | 0 | c**k** | 0.5 |
| **ki** | nk | 0 | **ki** | 1 |
| **in** | ki | 0 | **in** | 1 |
| **ng** | in | 0 | **ng** | 1 |
|  | ng | 0 |  |  |

**Desired score: 4** (i.e. column C)

I can get my letter combinations in pairs easily

```
first_word <- "booking"
second_word <- "blinking"

fw <- strsplit(first_word, "", 2)[[1]]    
fw_bg <- paste(head(fw, -1), tail(fw, -1), sep = "", collapse = NULL)

sw <- strsplit(second_word, "", 2)[[1]]    
sw_bg <- paste(head(sw, -1), tail(sw, -1), sep = "", collapse = NULL)

print(fw_bg)
# [1] "bo" "oo" "ok" "ki" "in" "ng"

print(sw_bg)
# [1] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "ki" "in" "ng"
```

I can apply the score to an individual pair:

```
sum(strsplit(fw_bg[1],"")[[1]] == strsplit(sw_bg[1],"")[[1]])/2
#[1] 0.5   

sum(strsplit(fw_bg[2],"")[[1]] == strsplit(sw_bg[2],"")[[1]])/2
#[1] 0

sum(strsplit(fw_bg[5],"")[[1]] == strsplit(sw_bg[6],"")[[1]])/2
#[1] 1
```

But I need some way to iterate through all the options on both fw_bg and sw_bg vectors to get the maximum possible score.

I could compute every possible permutation. But I can't figure out how to check for a matching permutation

```
x <- sw_bg

# Arrangements::combinations will create all the combinations for me
# including blank rows.
# But it sorts alphabetically - so need to make numerical matrix
# then populate the letter pairs.

mat <- unique(
        arrangements::combinations(
            x = c(1:(length(x)),
                 rep("", length(x)-1)),
            k = (length(x)))
       )
    
mt2 <- matrix(0, nrow = length(mat[,1]), ncol= length(mat[1,]))

# I'm sure there is a slicker way to do this bit
# but this bit works    
for (r in 1:length(mat[,1]) ){
    for (c in 1:length(mat[1,])) {
        mt2[r,c] <- x[as.numeric(mat[r,c])]
        }
    }

head(mt2)
```

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    [1,] "bo" "oo" "ok" "ki" "in" "ng"
    [2,] "bo" "oo" "ok" "ki" "in" NA  
    [3,] "bo" "oo" "ok" "ki" "ng" NA  
    [4,] "bo" "oo" "ok" "ki" NA   NA  
    [5,] "bo" "oo" "ok" "in" "ng" NA
```

I've done the same for sw_bg (into mt3):

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
    [1,] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "ki" "in" "ng"
    [2,] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "ki" "in" NA  
    [3,] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "ki" "ng" NA  
    [4,] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "ki" NA   NA  
    [5,] "bl" "li" "in" "nk" "in" "ng" NA
```

What I want is to compare / score:

```
    mt2[17,]:

    [17] "bo" "ok" "ki" "in" "ng" NA 

    mt3[49,]:

    [49] "bl" "nk" "ki" "in" "ng" NA   NA
```

But I presume I will need to score every combination for every combination on the two matrices.  Then select the maximum score.

```
# Replace NA with a double character (different in each matrix 
# so they don't match but can be split)
mt2[is.na(mt2)] <- "--"
mt3[is.na(mt3)] <- "=="

width = min(length(mt2[1,]), length(mt3[1,]))

score <- 0
for (r in 1: length(mt2[,1])) {
    for (rr in 1:length(mt3[,1])) {
        rr_score <- sum(unlist(strsplit(mt2[r,1:width],""))== unlist(strsplit(mt3[rr,1:width],"")), na.rm=T)/2
        if (rr_score > score) {
            score <- rr_score
        }
    }
    
}

cat(score)
# 4
```

Do people think there is a more efficient way to do this?

My script is fairly instant with smallish words.  But I will have some long words 10+ characters long to compare to another 10+ characters and it is taking over  a minute to do a single computation.

Comment: "Letter pairs can be omitted, but otherwise letter pairs can't be used out of sequence" are you allowed multiple gaps? e.g. if we had `took` and `okay`, can the `ok`s be compared?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.  The actual published implementation puts a different prefix character in front of the word which effectively gives extra points for the word starting with the same letter. to, oo, ok vs ok, ka, ay on my description above scores 1 for the ok's matching. In the published implementation they would use Tt, to, oo, ok, and Oo, ok, ka, ay which scores 1.5 (Oo ~ oo, ok = ok), and they divide it by the max word length (4) so this scores 0.375 on their implementation.  I tested teek and okay and it scores 0.125 (so there is a 0.5 score for the matching k in ok ~ ek)

Answer (score 0):

Your spending much time on `str_split` and `unlist` in your for-loops. If you substitute string matrix into character matrix with double amount of columns.

Then use standard `apply` and `expand.grid` to avoid nested `for`-loops.

```
...

mt2x <- t(apply(mt2, 1, function(x) (unlist(strsplit(x, "")))))
mt3x <- t(apply(mt3, 1, function(x) (unlist(strsplit(x, "")))))


widths <- seq(min(ncol(mt2x), ncol(mt3x)))

rows_to_compare <- expand.grid(seq(nrow(mt2x)), seq(nrow(mt3x)))
scores <- apply(rows_to_compare, 1, 
                function(x) sum(mt2x[x[1], widths] == mt3x[x[2], widths]) / 2)
max(scores)
...
```